# How to write reserve word in xml text part using python

Tags: python, xml

I tried to write the CDATA into XML, but the `<` and `>` always change to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. How can I correctly write the CDATA into XML file?

Here is parts of my code.

```
script = '<![CDATA[echo "something..."]]>'
xroot = etree.parse(xmlfile)
xpath = '//a:profile/a:scripts/a:post-scripts/a:script/a:source'
code = xmlroot.xpath(xpath)
code[0].text = script
```

The **result** always be `"&lt;![CDATA[echo "something..."]]&gt;"`

I already tried some method such as

- Using `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` and `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape`
- Add `\` before `<` and `>`

Both methods are not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are writing it correctly to XML. `<` and `>` are escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. When you retrieve your script back from XML you'll have to use `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape` to... well... obviously unescape them.

Comment: Do you mean that the CDATA is correct and could be run?

Comment: Yes. The string has just been escaped for storage in the XML. Once you read it back in, unescape it and you should have your original input.